# "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/mmcblk1"

Tags: release-juno

While installing Elementary OS for my Acer Spin 1 SP111-32N, it keeps on giving me this error at the very end of the installation. I know my computer uses an eMMC SSD drive, so maybe that is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have a laptop that utilizes an eMMC card as well and was able to get elementaryOS installed on it, but I did have to fiddle with some BIOS settings before any distro would install. Disabling SecureBoot as well as disabling firmware TPM. After that, choose the "try elementaryOS without installing option" instead of the install option when first booting from the live USB. Then, in the file manager, it's possible you'll see the eMMC mounted as an SD card or such. Unmount/eject it first, and then start the installer, and proceed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a while I found an easy solution.

Press fn+F2 key to enter  BIOS: 
Enable F12 Boot Menu
Set Supervisor Password
Disable Secure Boot
Press F10 to save and exit,

then press F12 to enter boot menu, and start live session.

Open your terminal and follow these steps to **install bootloader**.
Boot from live USB and open terminal:

```
sudo -s
fdisk -l 

mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt
# 0p2 is your file system partition (your root drive)
# 0p1 is your boot partition

mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
#create folders

mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/boot/efi
# mount boot partition in to new created folders

for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
# mount others systems directories

modprobe efivars
efibootmgr --verbose
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
grub-install -no-nvram -root-directory=/mnt
chroot /mnt
update-grub
```

Now you should be able to boot from eMMC SDD drive.

Source:
https://dantalion.nl/en/installing-ubuntu-on-acer-spin-uefi-devices/

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier solution to the problem, if you have 64GB on the drive (EMMC one), u just need 2 USBs and 1 external hard drive for the solution and the steps are:

1. create a bootable USB with Live ubuntu on it so u could boot into the try option.
2. connect the other USB stick (preferably to have 16GB - 64GB) and install the ubuntu on that stick.
3. boot from the live again, and just create an image disk from that 16-64GB USB that u just installed onto and save it onto the external Hard drive.
4. take both the hard drive (where u have the image of the installed USB 16-64GB) and the USB of the live boot and boot from the live one, then connect the hard drive and use the "restore image" option onto the EMMC drive, it will write the efi file system with the grub too onto the EMMC thus skipping the part where ubuntu itself tries to install the grub into the "SD Reader" (just make sure that u made it in GPT and not MBR since it works best on GPT and the acer spin also can boot from the UEFI option).
5. power off the PC after the operation is complete and disconnect all other devices and let it boot from the EMMC.
6. have fun.

if u got any other questions please feel free to contact me in discord: rmeir#2983
I come onto this forum once in a very long while.
(my friend just came onto here with his own acer spin and I solved him the problem)